# Update the field Created By (Author) in Sharepoint Online Programatically

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

How can I update the field `Created By(Author)` programmatically in SharePoint Online.

Comment: You can not update any read-only field!

Comment: I agree with Atish, you can not change read-only fields... Its just that ``Created`` (date) ``Author`` (Created by) are **not** read-only. You can even change the ``Modified`` fields... but that makes no sense as SharePoints updates them after you made a change.

Answer (score 2):

Below is the sample code that explains how to change the Created By field value using Client Object Model for SharePoint Online.

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using SP = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace updatecreatedby
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ClientContext clicon = new ClientContext("http://dotnetsharepoint.com/sites/SharePoint");
            SP.List list =clicon.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("yourlistname");
            clicon.Load(list);
            SP.ListItem item = list.GetItemById(22); //here item ID updating a single item
            clicon .Load(item);
            item["Author"] = GetUsers(clicon, "domainname\\createdname ");
            item.Update();

            item.Update();
            clicon.ExecuteQuery();

        }

        private static SP.FieldUserValue GetUsers(ClientContext clientContext, string UserName)
        {
            SP.FieldUserValue userValue = new SP.FieldUserValue();
            SP.User updateUser = clientContext.Web.EnsureUser(UserName);
            clientContext.Load(updateUser);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            userValue.LookupId = updateUser.Id;
            return userValue;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent code! I found this when already despaired with other advises. I can confirm that it really works. All possible credits to @Hardik !!!

Answer (score 0):

Running backend code on SharePoint Online is a bit cumbersome.

On a ListView Page This code assigns all Items to the current user

Run it in F12 developer tools or as CEWP/SEWP or CSR file or anywhere you want to run JavaScript:

```
function setAuthor(ID, authorID) {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current(),
        list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getById(SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList()),
        item = list.getItemById(ID);
    clientContext.load(item);
    item.set_item('Author', authorID);
    item.update();
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        function () {
            AJAXRefreshView({currentCtx: ctx,csrAjaxRefresh: true}, 1);
        },
        function (s, a) {
            console.error(a.get_message());
        }
    );
}
ctx.ListData.Row.forEach(function (row) {
    console.log('ItemID:', row.ID, 'was Author', row.Author[0]);
    setAuthor( row.ID , _spPageContextInfo.userId );
});
```

#### Note

- users have different IDs in different Site Collections

You can get the users in the current Web with:

```
function getWebUsers() {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = clientContext.get_web(); 
    var siteUsers = web.get_siteUsers();
    var users=[];
    clientContext.load(siteUsers);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        function() {
            userEnum=siteUsers.getEnumerator();
            while(userEnum.moveNext()){
               var user=userEnum.get_current();
               var userObject={
                   id:user.get_id()
                    ,email:user.get_email()
                    ,title:user.get_title()
                    ,loginName:user.get_loginName()
                    ,isSiteAdmin:user.get_isSiteAdmin()
                    ,isHiddenInUI:user.get_isHiddenInUI()
               };
               users.push(userObject);
               console.log(userObject);
            };
        }
        ,function(e,a){console.error(a)}
       );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please explore this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2941926/348158) for a weird hack necessary to update Author info in addition to valid code provided here.